# Return key of list value while searching for element in list Python

Tags: python

Let me give you an example for this. I have a dictionary

```
word = 'mango'
my_dict = {'A':['apple','banana','pear'],
          'B':['mango','carrot','guava'],
           'C':['orange','lemon','ginger']}
```

I want to be able to return 'B' as the answer by iterating through all the list/value elements . How could I do this? functions and comprehensions are both acceptable. Please help me out.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
word = 'mango'
my_dict = {'A':['apple','banana','pear'],
           'B':['mango','carrot','guava'],
           'C':['orange','lemon','ginger']}


def search_value():
  for key, _list in my_dict.items():
    if word in _list:
      return key

print(search_value()) # B
```